epoch time to pandas datetime or excel - giving wrong results
I have downloaded some shares tick data. The datetime comes as epoch time. Converting to pandas dataframe or excel gives me incorrect result. How do I correct it.

e.g. 1711943100
pd result : 2024-Apr-01 03:45AM
ditto for Excel.
However, if i use time.localtime(1711943100), it gives me correct result as :
time.struct_time(tm_year=2024, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=9, tm_min=15, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=92, tm_isdst=0)
I am using VSC for python.
Can't make out how to get rid/adjust for this time difference (UTC-Indiatime)
Expected result : 2024-Apr-01 09:15AM
